# Virtual printers going offline

Tags: offline, printers

I know that virtual printers can be made offline manually. But is it possible for a virtual printer to go offline due to some reason? If yes, Can you tell when this can happen? 
What will happen if the local port of virtual printer is deleted?

Answer (score 2):

You mean a printer connected through a local network? It's possible if there's something wrong with the printer's network adapter or wireless that prevents it from maintaining a connection to the network.